# How to set lock screen wallpaper to a live one

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I'm working on an android application and I need to set the lock screen wallpaper and normal wallpaper to an animated one. I use a custom Wallpaper Service and set it for the home screen using a new Intent. While this works for the home screen I haven't found a way to make it work on the lock screen, the closest I got is to get it to work on Samsung phones. Now I was wondering if I can do anything to reach my goal.

Here's my current implementation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER");
intent.putExtra("android.service.wallpaper.extra.LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT", new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, BorderlightWallpaperService.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your implementation?

Comment: I edited the message

Answer (score 0):

As of API Level 24 they have added new methods (and updated the documentation) and flags to the WallpaperManager which allow you to set a Wallpaper not only to the home screen but also to the Lockscreen

To set a Wallpaper to the Lockscreen use the new flag WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK, and one of the methods which take int which

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setStream(inputStream, null, true,WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
```

You can also use one of the following methods

```
int setStream (InputStream bitmapData,  Rect visibleCropHint,  boolean allowBackup, int which)

int setResource (int resid, int which)

int setBitmap (Bitmap fullImage, Rect visibleCropHint,  boolean allowBackup,  int which)
```

Comment: This is not what I'm lokking for. This only supports a bitmap, I need to use an animated wallpaper. This will not work